# Prevent Angular.js stripping html formatting out of a json file

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to iterate through data in a json file using Angular 1. One of the pieces of data contains HTML fieldsets and tabular data. Angular is stripping this out. How can I prevent this?

This is the code I am using for the app:

```
var app = angular.module( 'myApp', ['ngSanitize'] );

app.controller('crisisCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("data.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.mkyData = response.data.records;
    });
});
```

Json file (data.php):

```
{
  "records": [
    {

      "Card": "3",
      "Title": "Blah",
      "Content": "<fieldset class=\"table bt-0\"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Role</th><th>Number</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Bill</td><td> Director</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">304 304-3042</a></td></tr><tr><td>Mary</td><td>Technical</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">304 304-3042</a></td></tr><tr><td>Hannah</td><td>Engineer</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">120 104-4042</a></td></tr></tbody></fielset>"
        }
      ]
    }
```

And within my html file:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="crisisCtrl">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="x in myData">
        <div class="card-block" ng-bind-html="x.Content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an adjusted fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/deCcG/2/

Answer (score 1):

`thead` and `tbody` should be used in `table`. Your browser may accept it, but Angular does not.

Try to just update your `$scope.page.content` with:

```
"content":"<fieldset class=\"table bt-0\"><table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Role</th><th>Number</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Bill Williams</td><td>Widget Director</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">+1 304 304-3042</a></td></tr><tr><td>Mary Barnhill</td><td>Technical</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">+44 304 304-3042</a></td></tr><tr><td>Hannah Kwak</td><td>Engineer</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">+44 120 104-4042</a></td></tr></tbody></table></fieldset>"
```

**[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/t7q86juL/)**.

---

*Furthermore, you miss-spelled the closing `</fieldset>`.*

Comment: FYI, even with the proper spelling `fieldset` will be stripped out.  This is because `ng-bind-html` sanitizes input by default (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) and `fieldset` is not part of Angular's list of approved elements.  You will either have to customize the sanitization provider or explicitly trust the content (using `$sce.trustAsHtml`)

Comment: Also, a minor point but it is not angular that is stripping out the table fields.  It appears to be the jQuery/jQlite `html()` method that is doing it.  Just take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/fcomt4td/1/

Answer (score 0):

The `<fieldset class=\"table bt-0\">` is what is causing the issue, if you add a table element angular will then be able read the HTML being correctly formatted with correct elements and displays correctly

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.page = {
    "title": "Getting Started",
    "content": "<fieldset class=\"table bt-0\"><table><thead><tr><th>Name </th><th>Role</th><th>Number</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Bill Williams</td><td>Widget Director</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">+1 304 304-3042</a></td></tr><tr><td>Mary Barnhill</td><td>Technical</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">+44 304 304-3042</a></td></tr><tr><td>Hannah Kwak</td><td>Engineer</td><td><a href=\"tel:000\">+44 120 104-4042</a></td></tr></tbody></table></fieldset>"
  }
})
```

Comment: (*not the downvoter*) What do you mean by `The` and `Them`?

Comment: @Igor Sorry, was playing around with my reply and the code, my answer is now complete, should make sense now.